# .net obtener función de función (como ocurre con .ToString()

Tags: herencia, interface

Necesito armar una función (sub) que esté heredada de otra función

Ej.

```
Public Sub Ingreso(strID As String)
End Sub

Public Sub InfoAdicional(strInfo As String)
End Sub

Sub Main()
  'Necesito llamar de alguna manera esto
  Ingreso("123").InfoAdicional("Son 3 números")
End Sub
```

He intentado con herencia, clases, interfaces pero no consigo que funcione.
Gracias

Comment: Para que eso funcione, el método `Ingreso` debe devolver algún objeto que implemente el otro método llamado `InfoAdicional`.

Comment: No entiendo, podrías dar más detalles?

Comment: @MauricioContreras podrás darme un ejemplo con el código que hice en la pregunta?

Comment: @Yussef ToString() es un método de System.

ToString(), puede aplicarse a la función CDate(), por ejemplo.

Usando mi ejemplo, Ingreso sería ToString, InfoAdicional sería CDate()

Comment: @SergioHaurat No es como tú dices, CDate() es una función que retorna un objeto, especificamente un `Date` y `ToString` es una función de ese objeto, en ningún caso de CDATE. Creo que tienes un enredo de conceptos, lo mejor es que armes tu pregunta en términos básicos, clarificando el problema y la solución que esperas

Comment: @Yussef gracias por tu tiempo.  Yo necesito básicamente poder hacer lo siguiente

    Obj = Funcion("abc")
    Obj2 = Obj.Text("123")

ó

    Obj2 = Funcion("abc").Text("123")

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Según lo que entiendo tú quieres hacer lo que se llama [Chain Function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_chaining), la cual es una técnica que se usa para llamar funciones de un objeto múltiples veces.

La técnica es fácil de implementar, en todas las funciones debes retornar el objeto mismo, es decir `Me`.

Ejemplo:

```
Module Program
    Sub Main(args As String())
        Dim fun As New Funciones

        fun.Ingreso("asd").InfoAdicional("ad")
    End Sub


End Module

Class  Funciones
    Public Function Ingreso(strID As String) As Funciones

        'Algún código que hace cosas aca

        Return Me
    End Function


    Public Function InfoAdicional(strInfo As String) As Funciones

        'Algún código que hace cosas aca

        Return Me
    End Function
End Class
```

Comment: Excelente, estaba intentando heredar pero no encontraba como hacerlo correctamente.  Muchas gracias!